# Functions in go lang, can someone please break this down for me?

Tags: function, go, closures, lang

I was taking the tour of golang when I stumbled upon closures, one thing led to another and I landed at https://www.calhoun.io/5-useful-ways-to-use-closures-in-go/

Here I was stumped by the code snippet

```
func makeFibGen() func() int {
  f1 := 0
  f2 := 1
  return func() int {
    f2, f1 = (f1 + f2), f2
    return f1
  }
}
```

Can someone please break this down to me and explain what exactly is going on?
Especially this line:

```
f2, f1 = (f1 + f2), f2
```

Comment: It's handy for swapping variable values too without have to create a temporary variable e.g. `x, y = y, x`

Comment: See similar question [golang multiple assignment evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48836122/5728991).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f2` is assigned `f1 + f2` while at the same time `f1` is assigned (the original value of) `f2`. So if `f1, f2` were `3, 5` before, they would be `5, 8` (`5, (3 + 5)`) afterwards.

This way, we get a Fibonacci generator, because every time the inner function is called, the sum of the previous two values gets returned and saved for next time together with the larger one of the previous numbers, building the next pair that when added together will produce the next Fibonacci number, and so on.

Comment: Wow! Looking at that line after reading what you have said, it looks all clear! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also when you have a moment, can you please break this line down? How do I read it? func makeFibGen() func() int 
How do I read this?
A function declaration called makeFibGen() that takes in a func() as an input and returns an int as output?

Comment: no, a function `makeFibGen` that takes no arguments (`()`) and returns a `func() int`, that is, it returns a function with no arguments (`()`) that returns an `int`.

Comment: The purpose is that the inner function that is returned from the outer function has its own "environment" in form of the variables defined in the outer function (which will be different variables every time the outer function is called). The term for this sort of mechanism is "closure".

Comment: thanks a lot @CherryDT